# Codification problems (and basics) with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I know that the definition of this question can seem may seem too nonspecific, so I will try to provide all the associated data.

In this ocasion I'm acting like a hoster. We have a PHP page working against MySQL. Somebody did some operation over the MySQL instance, that has induced problems visualizing problematic characters (ñ, accents, etc) (And that's all, it's a mistery).

I've tested a lot of options, but I think that my lack of knowledge makes me blind. I know that it's common so maybe we can build some kind of 'checklist'.

If I type 'status' on the MySQL instance I get:

```
Server version:         5.5.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:               3306
```

Everything in UTF8...great!. If I connect with HeidiSQL and inspect the variables I get:

```
character_set_client     utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database   utf8
collation_collection     utf8_general_ci
collation_database       utf8_general_ci
```

And etc. etc. However, and unfortunately visiting the page returns weird characters as �. The content charset in META tags is also UTF-8.

I know that some modifications can be done in code in order to force the connection to occur in some charset. But, apart from that, the most incredible thing is that the page was working.

Anybody knows what has benn altered in the server to induce this behavior?

Thanks a lot as always!

**PS: We are especially interested in aspects that comes from server configurations. Change client's source code is something that we want to avoid.**

Comment: So it was working before but has ceased working now? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Yes, We believe it is because of an operation that someone has done... So we would like to know what kind of config updates can lead to this. Thanks Pekka :)

Answer (score 2):

What about the HTTP header? If in the header is a character encoding definition then the meta definition will not get applied.

Comment: How can I know more about the HTTP header?.  Using HTTP inspectors I see UTF8 as accepted charset and returned, but nothing more.

Comment: In the response header you should see Content-Type: [...] if there is any.

Comment: Appears: Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 2):

If your code enters data into MySQL without setting the charset to UTF, that will probably result in your problems:

After connecting to DB and DB table, run:

```
mysql_set_charset ( 'utf-8' );
```

The default communication charset between PHP and MySQL is still not UTF-8.

Comment: `The default communication charset between PHP and MySQL is still not UTF-8.` I'm not sure whether this is true if it has been forced to UTF-8 in the mySQL config?

Comment: Thanks fred2. The thing is, I know that the behavior is caused by some modification in the server. Modify the application client code it's something that we want avoid.

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things for me? How did the 'operation over the mysql instance' happen. Eg, was it done directly from the command line to mysql, or via an import from a mysql dump file, via phpMyAdmin, or via some other client? Is the data that is displaying corrupted character data that was in the database BEFORE this operation (in which case it's a case of the server displaying the wrong charset), or data that was introduced BY or AFTER the operation (in which case the data in the database is in the wrong charset, and not sure there's a way to fix it)?

Comment: Hi again Fred2 and thanks for your time. We think that the change was done with some client (maybe console or HeidiSQL with root privileges). The data was BEFORE in the database, so I'm thinking too that the server is sending to the clients the wrong charset. However, if I list the related variables they always appear in UTF8.

Comment: Hmmm. Funnily enough, my own MySQL database is set to encoding 'latin 1' for just about everything - but it restores and sends UTF-8 data fine, including lots of weird characters. The thing is that the data is stored in binary form, so as I understand it, the charset does not matter too much, so long as whatever is displaying the data (in this case PHP) knows it should be displaying it as UTF-8. So, ironically, if data goes in as UTF-8 character codes and is interpreted as UTF-8 codes when it comes out, it will be displayed as UTF-8, even if the database is latin 1....continued next comment.

Comment: So, even though you don't want to mess with the PHP code, I'd really like to see what happens if you try mysql_set_charset ( 'utf-8' );

Comment: It could be nothing happens, but I'd want to rule it out. You could try it in a test php script that queries the database, rather than modifying the code. Other than that, all I can think of is that someone did an mysql_dump and mysql restore from the dump file and messed up the character set on the text file the data was in. Or, a bad php connection from some bit of code that did a process (even a replace of data with the same data) could have caused it.